# Hibernate reactive No Vert.x context active in aws rds

Tags: mysql, hibernate, vert.x, hibernate-reactive

I randomly receive this exception within my application:
HR000065: No Vert.x context active

java.lang.IllegalStateException: HR000065: No Vert.x context active

> 2021-11-09T17:12:18.143+02:00 at
> org.hibernate.reactive.context.impl.VertxContext.put(VertxContext.java:41)
> ~[hibernate-reactive-core-1.0.1.Final.jar!/:1.0.1.Final]
>
> 2021-11-09T17:12:18.143+02:00 Suppressed:
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
>
> 2021-11-09T17:12:18.143+02:00 Error has been observed at the following
> site(s):
>
> 2021-11-09T17:12:18.143+02:00 |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler
> com.nflp.processingapplication.main.modules.authentication.controller.PrincipalController#getUserAuthentication()
> [DispatcherHandler]
>
> 2021-11-09T17:12:18.143+02:00 |_ checkpoint ⇢
> com.nflp.processingapplication.main.modules.api.shared.filter.ApiExceptionFilter

It does not always occur, but after a couple of times, I start receiving timeout exceptions on any request to the db, which looks like the connection is never released.
Also, I only receive this error in the prod environment - we are using aws rds, it works perfectly fine locally, even when I create an ssh tunnel to the rds instance and connect to prod db locally.
I only use methods like withTransaction and withSession in my application, so I do not expect it to be an issue with implementation of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was related to the fact that I was using `Stage.Session` implementation of the api and converting it into the Reactive Java streams [Flux, Mono]using Mono.fromCompleationStage().
After switching to Mutiny api I was no longer able to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Hello @Dmytro Kostyushko, I'm looking for example, how to use `VertxContext` along the mutiny pipeline (reactive stream), do you mind showing a few lines of code?